# Changing color theme of certain things in vscode ( react )

Tags: json, reactjs, visual-studio-code, themes

I have recently started to learn React.js and I have a Lil problem here, trying to edit some **colors** in ayu theme. The thing is I want a **separate** color for '***state***' and '***variables***' of const. Are there any specific scopes for those?

I have sth like this but it changes every variable in the code - should I add sth to this to make it work?:

{
      "name": "Variable",
      "scope": ["variable"],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#fff"
      }

[I want to change the colors of the marked ones **only**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwNlr.png)

Answer (score 1):

settings---> color theme --> select your theme

there are multiple themes which you can download in extensions , possibly help you diffrentiate.

Comment: That's not what i meant but figured it out already. You need to configure developer scope tm, and you are all done :D

Ty anyway :)